# Is is possible to add additional column to SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I have successfully used a SimpleCursorAdapter to list displayname and value (both in my DB) and displayed them in my list activity.

What I am was trying to do now was add a new view (ImageView) for each item in my list activity. It is supposed to look like this in the end.

```
Image_1_NotInDB -- DisplayName1FromDB -- DisplayName1FromDB
Image_2_NotInDB -- DisplayName2FromDB -- DisplayName2FromDB.
```

The image is going to different (based on DisplayName1FromDB). I don't think SimpleCursorAdapter is good anymore for this purpose.

I tried creating a customSimpleCursorAdapter extending SimpleCursorAdapter and tried to use 'newView' and 'bindView' methods to achieve. I pretty much followed this: [Custom CursorAdapters](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/).

The problem is; what Image I use is based on a value from DB (which I intended to pass in the constructor or customSimpleCursorAdapter)

```
public View newView(Context pContext, Cursor pCursor, ViewGroup pParent)
{
    Cursor lCursor = getCursor();
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(pContext);
    View lView = inflater.inflate(layout, pParent, false);
    int lImage = "dog".equals(variable) ? R.drawable.dog : R.drawable.cat;
    // "variable" is a member variable (set at the constructor)
    ImageView lImageView = (ImageView) lView.findViewById(R.id.appImage);
    if (lImageView != null)
    {
        lImageView.setImageResource(lImage);
    }
    return pParent;
}

public void bindView(View pView, Context pContext, Cursor pCursor)
{
    int lImage = "dog".equals(variable) ? R.drawable.dog : R.drawable.cat;
    // "variable" is a member variable (set at the constructor)
    ImageView lImageView = (ImageView) lView.findViewById(R.id.appImage);
    if (lImageView != null)
    {
        lImageView.setImageResource(lImage);
    }
}
```

This is how I tried using the "customSimpleCursorAdapter"

```
    String[] lDisplay = new String[] {KEY_NAME, KEY_TIME};
    int[] lValues = new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.time};
    CustomRowCursorAdapter lCursorAdapter = new CustomRowCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, lSTime, lDisplay, lValues, "MY IDEA WAS TO PASS THE ANIMAL NAME HERE, BUT NOT LUCK as I am not sure How ");
    lCursorAdapter.newView(this, lSTime, getListView());
    lCursorAdapter.bindView(getListView(), this, lSTime);
    setListAdapter(lCursorAdapter);
```

Is ArrayAdapter the answer? If yes, could you share what parameters would you pass to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to go for custom adapter

Comment: any hints on how to get started on this?

Comment: you can refer to link http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/06/custom-adapter-in-color.html or http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327 
let me know was that helpful to you.. if you find it difficult, pass me the layout you want in the listview and I will pass you the code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is ArrayAdapter the answer?

No you can not use the `ArrayAdapter` here. Because you need to display data from the database therefore you must use here a Custom `CursorAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional field to the projection from the database.

Here is an example of a projection I have used to format a cost based off of the a price of an item (stored in cents) and an associated unit.

```
public static final String CONCATE_COST
    = "'$' || CASE WHEN SUBSTR(ROUND("+COLUMN_PRICE
        +"/100.0, 2), LENGTH(ROUND("+COLUMN_PRICE
        +"/100.0, 2))-1, 1)='.' THEN ROUND("+COLUMN_PRICE
        +"/100.0, 2) || '0' else ROUND("+COLUMN_PRICE
        +"/100.0, 2) end || "+COLUMN_UNIT;
```

Use that as a column and you can pair it with a field in your view using the normal mapping of `column` to `R.id.*`.